# While entering the Google message App .It shows Someone has Access to your screen dialog

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-mediaprojection, android-14

Issue:  I need to capture the screen using media projection permission now in the Android 14 device. whenever I enter a Google messages App the warning dialog shows that someone has permission to access the screen. In the background, my app is taking a screenshot for every 30 sec. My question is there any way to bypass the dialog and capture the screen? or any permission I need to get from the user to capture the Current running App. any suggestion from your end that might be helpful.Thanks in Advance!!
**
Note: My app is not for Playstore**

I have looked into developer documents but I can't find them. is their any loop hole for this

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is no different from a malware app. It would be better not to let the app work like that, rather than finding a way to solve the problem from Google message app's dialog.

Comment: I found the answer @Akexorcist

Comment: @Kiruba Use SmsManager to access the message in SMS directly?

Comment: no insted of that i used the flag  which is mentioned in Developer document so it worked it charm that's alla @Akexorcist